# Variable with WhereNotIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got a variable with

> 2,3

... And I pass to my function by POST:

```
        //echo $_POST['sponsored_inserts']; returns 2,3
        $sponsored_link = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
            ->where('sponsored', 1)
            ->with('page', 'tag')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->WhereNotIn('id', [$_POST['sponsored_inserts']])
            ->first();
```

The WhereNotIn remove only the id 2 from search... But, if I put:

```
    $sponsored_link = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('sponsored', 1)
        ->with('page', 'tag')
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->WhereNotIn('id', [$_POST['sponsored_inserts'],3])
        ->first();
```

Works...

What's happening?

Comment: Main thing is to provide array in the `whereNotIn() `, check the type of the variable you are using

Comment: You got variable `2,3` what is the type of variable string or array ?

Comment: Thank you, solved!

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso: how did you solve this, what was the problem ?

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso Anyway congrats I still don't know problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable is a **string type** if it's like *2,3* separated by comma does not mean it's an array.

`WhereNotIn()` function accepts an array as a second parameter, So `$_POST['sponsored_inserts'] = [2,3]` is acceptable

you need to do :

```
$sponsoredInserts = explode(',',$_POST['sponsored_inserts']);
```

And in your query

```
->WhereNotIn('id',$sponsoredInserts);
```